# Write stl class to data.frame and/or csv

Tags: r

I used the STL function in the {stats} package to seasonally detrend some time series data.

I would now like the results exported to csv, but when I try

```
write.csv(mySTLdata, "mySTLdata.csv")
```

I get the error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""stl"" to a data.frame
```

If I try to just convert the STL to a data.frame, it again tells me it cannot be coerced into one.

Any ideas on how I can get this out of the R environment for use elsewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going to leave this for anyone else who needs it in the future, but I figured it out.

To coerce an stl class into a data.frame, simply:

```
mySTLdata.DF <- as.data.frame(mySTLdata$time.series)
```

I was leaving off the $time.series part.

Comment: Don't you lose the dates with this? I was going to suggest `library(xts); as.data.frame(as.xts(mySTLdata$time.series))`.